# How to turn off headphones, and only leave enabled analog output?

Tags: sound, headphones, output

How to turn off **Headphones**, and only leave enabled **Analog Output**? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to **System Settings - - > Sound**

Then you can configure your sound settings from there...  :)